# Displaying List<Object[]> in a JSP with Struts 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have an issue with Struts2. I created a `List<Object[]> myList` and filled it with a query result.

My query get fields from two tables so I can't put the result on a bean instance (I guess).
I would like to display `myList` on a JSP with Struts2 trough an iterator but I can't get the values of the list.

On the DAO (I use Hibernate):

```
List<Object[]> myList = session.createQuery("select a.name, b.description, c.description from test a, test2 b where a.id = b.id ");
```

On the JSP, If I use this code:

```
<s:iterator value="myList">
<tr>    
    <td><s:property/></td>
    <td><s:property/></td>
</tr>
```

It's display just one column of the list.

I tried this

```
<s:iterator value="myList" var="unElem">
    <td><s:property value="unElem.name"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="%{#unElem.description}" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="%{unElem.name}" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="%{#unElem.description}" /></td>  
</s:iterator>
```

But it's not working. Do you have an idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: its not working  ? please expand it

Comment: Your list contains elements of type `Object[]`. `Object[]` doesn't have any getName() or getDescription() method.Why don't you transform, in your controller, your `List<Object[]>` into a `List<SomeBean>`?

Comment: When I said "it's not working" that means nothing is displayed on the browser. I used the answer below and the result is well display. I don't have any bean which correspond to my query result that why I put it on a list of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You list elements which you are used with the iterator tag might contain `Object[]`. It doesn't clear what type is `myList` or you are using DAO for your action bean that is worse. Struts can display those objects using OGNL notation but you will not be able to populate that list back if you will try to submit values. To display values of `Object[]` you just need to access them by the column index.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <th>Description:</th>
    <th>Description:</th>  
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<s:iterator value="myList" var="unElem">
  <tr>
    <td><s:property value="%{#unElem[0]}"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="%{#unElem[1]}"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="%{#unElem[2]}"/></td>  
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It works thank you ! I use the DAO to access to the DB. Since I don't have any bean corresponding to my query result I put it on list of object (I'm not really good with java as you can see). Otherwise I use JSP => Action class => Model class => DAO => Hibernate.

Comment: Hibernate can return entity's objects if you don't specify `select` keyword in the query, otherwise it has many useful result transformers like `aliasToBean` you can use to produce DTOs. Everything about it you can find in the Hibernate reference manual. Happy codding.

Comment: @Superman This answer is 10 years old, and it's not relevant to your problem. Don't post your irrelevant comments here.