# show a list of arrays of objects List(Object[]) in struts select tag <s:select>

Tags: struts2, ognl

```
<s:select label="Motif de la réclamation"
            name="motifBean.motifId"                      
            list="%{motifListBean}" listKey="motifId"  listValue="libelle" value="1">

    </s:select>
```

I use select tag like above but I don't know how to do it when i habe not keys and values but rather an Object[] inside the list

Thanks

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22435289/573032

Comment: I know how to use iterator over a list of object[] but not in the select tag

Comment: Select tag is using the iterator internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no answer. I converted the Obect[]  to a Map
and used the map in the select tag